# Is there an isometry between the direct sum of $L^1(\mu_i)$ and $L^1(\nu)$, i.e. $\bigoplus_{i} L^1(\mu_i)\cong L^1(\nu)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, isometry, direct-sum

In https://math.stackexchange.com/a/74877/653080 it is mentioned that $\mathcal{M}(K)\cong L^1(\nu)$ for some measure $\nu$, whereas [$\mathcal M(K)$ is an $\mathcal{l}_1-$sum of $L_1(\mu)$ spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1532956/653080) is it mentioned that $\mathcal{M}(K)\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I} L^1(\mu_i)$ for some mutually singular probability measures $\mu_i$. This hints at that $\bigoplus_{i\in I} L^1(\mu_i)\cong L^1(\nu)$.

Does this mean that in general there exists a (probability) measure $\nu$ such that $\bigoplus_{i\in I} L^1(\mu_i)\cong L^1(\nu)$, when $\mu_i$ are mutually singular probability measures $\mu_i$? If so, can we choose $\nu$ to be any probability measure $\nu$ with full support on $K$?

The spaces $\bigoplus_{i\in I} L^1(\mu_i)$ and $L^1(\nu)$ are defined as
$$
   L^1(\nu) = \{f:K\to\mathbb{R}^d \;|\; \int_K|f(x)|d\nu(x) < \infty \} \\
   \bigoplus_{i\in I} L^1(\mu_i) = \{ (f_1,f_2...) \;|\; f_i\in L^1(\mu_i)\}
$$
with norms
$$
    ||f||_{L^1(\nu)} = \int_K|f(x)|d\nu(x) \\
    ||f||_{\bigoplus_{i\in I} L^1(\mu_i)} = \sum_{i\in I}||f_i||_{L^1(\mu_i)}
$$

Comment: Your description of $\bigoplus L^1(\mu_i)$ is incorrect.  Note that $I$ is not countable.

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not work. In particular, note that the space $(K, \mathcal{B}(K), \nu )$ is a finite (hence, separable) measure space. This implies (e.g. see Brezis Theorem 4.13) that $L^1(\nu )$ is a separable Banach space, but then it cannot be isometrically isomorphic to $\mathcal{M}(K)$, which is non-separable in general.

Comment: Based on this answer, https://mathoverflow.net/a/340218/137295, I think you are right that $\mathcal{M}(K)$ is not seperable in general when it has the norm topology, but it is with the weak* topology. However your answer does not address the posed question, which is about the isometry between a direct sum of $L^1$ and another $L^1$.