# Is $C[0,1]$ reflexive?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, duality-theorems

I.e. is the embedding $C[0,1]\hookrightarrow \left( C[0,1] \right)^{**}$ surjective?

I am having a hard time answering that question. It would be enough to find a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$ which is not reflexive since closed subspaces in reflexive spaces are again reflexive. Is there a canonical such subspace? Or alternatively, is there an easy description of the dual/double-dual of $C[0,1]$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One need not to know the whole dual space of $C[0,1]$ to see the lack of reflexivity.

Simply note that $C[0,1]^*$, opposed to $C[0,1]$, is non-separable because for each $t\in [0,1]$ the map $$\langle f, \delta_t\rangle = f(t)\quad (f\in C[0,1])$$ is a norm-one linear functional on $C[0,1]$ and $\|\delta_t - \delta_s\| =2$ for distinct $s,t$. To see this, take a norm-one function $f$ such that $f(t)=-1, f(s)=1$. As $\{\delta_t\colon t\in [0,1]\}$ is an uncountable, discrete subset of $C[0,1]^*$, $C[0,1]^*$ cannot be separable.

Comment: This implies that $C[0,1]$ isn't reflexive because reflexivity of $X^*$ implies that of $X$.

Comment: @Jochen, if it were reflexive $C[0,1]^{**}$ and hence $C[0,1]^*$ would be separable.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not.

The dual of $C[0,1]$ is the space $\mathfrak{M}([0,1])$ of complex (or signed) regular Borel measures on $[0,1]$.

The dual of $\mathfrak{M}([0,1])$ *contains* the set $\mathcal L^\infty([0,1])$ of bounded Borel functions on $[0,1]$.

For example, $\chi_{\{0\}}$, the function which vanishes everywhere, except at $x=0$, where it is equal to $1$, defines a bounded linear functional on $\mathfrak{M}([0,1])$, namely
$$
\varphi(\mu)=\int \chi_{\{0\}}\,d\mu=\mu(\{0\}),
$$
which is not representable by an element of $C[0,1]$.

Another proof. According to Kakutani's Theorem, *A space is reflexive if the closed unit ball of $X$ is compact in the weak topology*. Note that, the sequence $\,f_n=\mathrm{e}^{2\pi nx i}\in C[0,1]$ does not possess a weakly converging subsequence.

Comment: Is there a way to see it if I don't know the dual of $C[0,1]$?

Comment: @TheRealBritneySpears: That is the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: Huh. For some reason I thought the second dual was larger than that. (No hints please; want to think about it...)

Comment: Quibble: Probably saying "complex (or real)" would be better. At least in many people's terminology a signed measure takes values in $[-\infty,\infty]$, not necessarily in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: W. Rudin calls the real valued $\sigma-$additive set-functions *signed measures*.

Comment: I was surprised to hear that the second dual was what you say. Turns out it's not, explaining why I couldn't quite prove it. Found a counterexample, started posting something and "possibly related" stuff popped up: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47544/double-dual-of-the-space-c0-1/1648540#1648540

Comment: One has $C[0,1]^{**} \cong (\bigoplus_{i\in I}L_\infty(\mu_i))_{\ell_\infty(I)}$, where $(\mu_i)_{i\in I}$ is a maximal family of pairwise singular probability measures on $[0,1]$.